# Question about regular sequences of homogeneous polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm faced with a statement that I'm struggling with. To paraphrase:

> Let $ (z_{1},\dots,z_{M}) $ is a system of affine coordinates with some centre $ o \in V. $ And let $ f = q_{1}+q_{2}+\dots+q_{M} $ be the equation of a hypersurface $ V $ of degree $ M $ where $ q_{i}(z_{1},\dots,z_{M}) $ is a homogenous polynomial of degree $ i. $ A point in $ x \in V $ is regular, if $ q_{1},\dots,q_{M-1} $ creates a regular sequence in $ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{M},x} $ that is, the system of equations $$ q_{1} = q_{2}  = \dots = q_{M-1} = 0 $$ defines a finite set of lines in $ \mathbb{P}^{M} $ passing through $ o \in \mathbb{P}^{M-1}.$

I know that if $ R $ is a commutative ring, and $ M $ is an $ R-$module, then a sequence $ x_{1},\dots,x_{r} $ of elements of $ R $ is said to be $ M-$regular if: 
$$ (x_{1},\dots,x_{r})M \neq M, $$  and  $$ x_{i} \text{ is a non-zero divisor on }  M/(x_{1},\dots,x_{r}) \text{ for each }  i = 1,\dots,r. $$

I'm having a hard time seeing how the fact that $ q_{1},\dots,q_{M-1} $ creates a regular sequence leads to $ q_{1} = q_{2} = \dots = q_{M-1} = 0 $ defining a set of lines in $ \mathbb{P}^{M}. $

Comment: This looks interesting, but I have some concerns. First, what is the setting? Presumably, it's at least a variety over a field, but are there any other assumptions made here? Your notation $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^M,x}$ suggests that you're working with your variety inside $\Bbb P^M$, but then you talk about $o\in \Bbb P^{M-1}$. Next, what about the example $V(y-x^2)\subset \Bbb A^2$ and the point $p=(1,1)$? Then this is smooth, but $x$ is invertible in the local ring of $p$, violating your statement. To help fix these issues, can you provide the source for the statement you're paraphrasing?

Comment: @KReiser This is from Page 121 of "'Birationally Rigid Varieties" by Pukhlikov. Sorry for the delay.